# How design a filter to obtain a desired autocorrelation in output

Tags: filters, filter-design, autocorrelation

I have a signal x(n) with a given autocorrelation function ACF, $R_x(\tau) \neq 0$ for $\tau=1, \cdots ,L$
My question is how can i design a filter (better with a few coefficients) to obtain a signal $y(n) $with a desired ACF,e.g., $R_y(\tau)\approx 0$, for $\tau=1,2$

I tried with an AR(1) filter setting empirically two coefficients and it works, but a failed to find a general
Maybe in the frequency domain?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you want a whitening filter but optimized for just the first two lags?

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome, you're right. Actually i want to implement a "partial" whitening

Answer (score -1):

I am going to use a slightly different notation in my answer than was in the original question so I want to start out with some definitions.

$x[n]$ - The input signal at time index $n$, $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
$R_x[k]$ - [Autocorrelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Autocorrelation&oldid=1059192357) function (ACF) of $x[n]$ at lag $k$

I will assume that $x[n]$ real, and that it is [wide-sense stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process#Weak_or_wide-sense_stationarity) such that the ACF is only a function of the lag.

It is desired to find a linear filter, $h[n]$, that can be applied to $x[n]$ to generate a new signal $y[n]$:
$$y[n] = h[n] \ast x[n]$$
such that $R_y[k] \approx 0$ when $k \in \{1, 2\}$

This is a [spectral whitening](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Whitening_transformation&oldid=1041531734) problem.

First, define a 5x5 autocorrelation matrix based on $R_k[k]$:
$$\textbf{R}_{xx} = \begin{bmatrix}
R_x[0] & R_x[1] & \cdots & R_x[4]\\
R_x[-1] & R_x[0] & \cdots & R_x[3]\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
R_x[-4] & R_x[-3] & \cdots & R_x[0]
\end{bmatrix}$$

The desired moving ([finite impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Finite_impulse_response&oldid=1069096902) [FIR]) filter solves the desired problem is given by:
$$\textbf{h} = \textbf{R}_{xx}^{-1/2}\textbf{b}$$
where
$$\textbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$$
and
$$\textbf{h} = \begin{bmatrix}h[-2] & h[-1] & h[0] & h[1] & h[2]\end{bmatrix}^T$$

**Example of Before and After ACF**
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however it is not straightforward to me how you obtain the expression $\textbf{h} = \textbf{R}_{xx}^{-1/2}\textbf{b}$ 
Did  you use the z-tranform? Thanks in advance